# Unable to get value from serialize data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

Actually i just trying to get all input data from serialize but i get the values in int type like age & id but unable to get value of name.
following is my code.

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <form id ="form" method="post" class= "form">
            Name<input type = "text" name = "name" /><br>
            Age<input type = "number" name = "age" /><br>
            ID<input type = "number" name = "id" /><br>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit"><br/>
        </form>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#form").submit(function () {
                    var data = $("#form").serialize();
                    insertStudent(data);
                    return false;
                });
                function insertStudent(data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'process.php',
                        data: data,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data, textStatus) {
                            $("#result").html(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Not OKay');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
print_r($_POST);// give error but if i try to get id then
print_r($_POST["id"])// print value
print_r($_POST["name"])// doesn't print name
```

Comment: can you post your xhr request body and headers?

Comment: Your code is working fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/85rkbx27/. You need to debug the request in the browser console. Check the content of the request to make sure it matches what you expect.

Comment: you don't have a form element with the name id so your on the wrong page

Comment: In the success function you're doing `$("#result").html(data);` but the ajax call has `dataType: 'json'`. Change to `dataType: 'html'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").submit(function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var data =$(this).serialize();
        insertStudent(data);
        return false;
    });
    function insertStudent(data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#result").html(data);
                // console.log(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Not OKay');
            }
    });
    }
});
```